# displaying arraylist in inverse

Tags: java

hope someone could help me , I want to display my Last 5 object in my arraylist But , there is something wrong in my code :( , need help please

```
   for(int i=savedPreventivemachineList.size()-1 ; i < 5  ; i--)
   {
     Listresult.add(savedPreventivemachineList.indexOf(i), interventionmachine);
   }
   savedPreventivemachineTopList=Listresult;
```

when I execute it shows me this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: -1, Size: 0
java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(Unknown Source)
java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: for(int i=savedPreventivemachineList.size()-1 ; i >-1  ; i--) maybe? You're going down, not up, so you need to compare until it get 0 position. And your loop is gonna be endless (not really, until outOfBoundsException)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `ListIterator`

```
final ListIterator<String> thingIter = things.listIterator(things.size());
for (int i = 0; i < 5 && thingIter.hasPrevious(); ++i) {
    final String thing = thingIter.previous();
}
```

I think this is a little clearer as there isn't a decrementing loop.

Answer (score 3):

Inverse the condition:

```
for(int i=savedPreventivemachineList.size()-1 ; i > -1  ; i--)
```

Set the condition as `i>-1` or `i>=0`. Remember a `List list` of size: `list.size()` is indexed from `0` to `list.size()-1`. The reverse order will be `list.size()-1` to `0`, as the counter `i` is gradually decreasing from *size()-1,size()-2, .... ,2,1,0*.

You can even use a **[ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)** for this purpose, **that would be safer .**

> An iterator for lists that allows the programmer to traverse the list in either direction, modify the list during iteration, and obtain the iterator's current position in the list. A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and the element that would be returned by a call to next().

You can read [Iterating through a list in reverse order in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2102552/1163607) to get a hint.

> I want to display my Last 5 object in my arraylist

Then the condition should be `((i>savedPreventivemachineList.size()-6) && (i > -1))` . You want the last `5` elements hence `savedPreventivemachineList.size()-6` , you need to consider that the index doesn't fall below `0` , hence `i>-1` .

Comment: OP is asking for last 5 objects of the list. your loop goes through all list by inverse order.

Answer (score 3):

Your counter `i` gets smaller than 0.

use `(i > savedPreventivemachineList.size() - 5) && (i >= 0)` as condition.

Comment: OP's is asking for last 5 objects of the list. `i >= 0` will not satisfy this requirement.

Comment: yep... saw that to late

Answer (score 3):

To list last 5 objects of a list to your list, loop should run for five times.

For example if size of list is 34

Last accessible index is -> 34 - 1 = 33

Therefore last five indexes are -> 33,32,31,30,29

so size - 6 = 28 meaning that your loop should run until size -6

here is the code.

```
for(int i=savedPreventivemachineList.size()-1 ; i > savedPreventivemachineList.size()-6  ; i--)
   {
     Listresult.add(savedPreventivemachineList.indexOf(i), interventionmachine);
   }
   savedPreventivemachineTopList=Listresult;
```

Furthermore, you should check loop index will never go negative values.

To do this, change loop condition by adding `i >-1` condition.

```
for(int i=savedPreventivemachineList.size()-1 ; i > savedPreventivemachineList.size()-6 && i >-1 ; i--)
```

Comment: dude, i realized the mistake and posted the correct solution. i hope the new one is correct sol . :P

Answer (score 2):

Your code as it is now can lead to two scenario's:

1. If the array size > 5, the condition "i < 5" will fail on the first iteration (because i will be 5 or greater) and your loop will do nothing.
2. If the array size is 5 or less, "i < 5" will never be false, and the loop will continue forever. This fails because when i becomes less than 0, you are out of bounds of your array.

To solve this:
for(int i =savedPreventivemachineList.size()-1 ; i >= 0 && i >= savedPreventivemachineList.size()-5 ; i--)

It will now count back, and step out of the loop if either i becomes -1 (failsafe to prevent out of index errors) or as soon as i is smaller than the size of the array - 5. (reached the 5th item)

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.reverse(savedPreventivemachineList);
```

Then use `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: -1, Size: 0
>   Shows IndexOutOfBoundsException

Simply `int i=savedPreventivemachineList.size()-1` is -1
ie `savedPreventivemachineList.size()` is `Zero`

**Forward iteration**

```
for(Iterator<String> iter = savedPreventivemachineList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
  String item = iter.next();
  //item do what u want
}
```

**Backward iteration**

```
for(int i=savedPreventivemachineList.size()-1 ; i >= 0  ; i--)
```

**if it is List**

```
List<String> orderList = *****
List<String> reverseList = Lists.reverse(orderList);
```

Answer (score 0):

@erencan, thanks, i have realized the mistake. :)

```
int size = list.size()-1;
for(int i=size; i>=(size-5); i--){
```

I hope this isn't wrong. :)