# Reverse Java full document

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader, reverse, stringbuilder

I used reverse a string, but now need the final document is the principle, and vice versa:

```
Hello
Bye
```

to

```
Bye
hello
```

and not:

```
olleH
eyB
```

As I do this?

This is my source:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.err.println("Sintaxis incorrecta, introduzca el nombre del fichero");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        String s;

        try {
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(s);
                String sCadenaInvertida = reverse.reverse().toString();
                System.out.println(sCadenaInvertida);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Please rephrase `but now need the final document is the principle, and vice versa:`. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: split into words, reverse the collection, join using space

Comment: You need to take the String, use `split` to get an array of the words, then make a new String, reading the words in descending order. Simple :D

Comment: Before you post your question take a look at preview section to see if your question presents your problem correctly. I edited your question a little to show *how you wrote examples*, but I am not sure why some of upper case becomes lower case, so add more informations about input and expected output.

Comment: For now it looks like you need FILO like structure like stack, or just  add each line to some list and after you are done with adding [read it backward](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2102552/1393766).

Answer (score 2):

Just put everything in an ArrayList and use `Collections.reverse`
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ReverseorderofallelementsofJavaArrayList.htm

pseudo code:

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add("Hello");
    arrayList.add("Bye");

    Collections.reverse(arrayList);
    System.out.println(arrayList);
```

Comment: That would only do it by lines, not words

Comment: agreed but it doesn't say anything about reversing words.  I think they just want the lines in reverse order from the input.

Comment: Exactly, need to do what Scott says

Comment: need this:

hello, my house is white
bye, my mum is bad

Bye, my mum is bad
Hello, my house is white

reverse order from document, and not reverse words.

Comment: @Dan Even if it were by words, the logic would still apply of using a list + Collections.reverse

Comment: @user3482300 - The problem is that your original example is ambiguous.  It ALSO shows the document being reversed by words.  Your bad!

Answer (score 1):

Add the items to an array (first come first serve) then traverse the array in reverse

```
for (into I = array.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    //print array[i]
}
```

Alternatively you can use an ArrayList if you don't know the number of lines in the document

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> theWords= new ArrayList<String>();
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //split line into words
            String[] parts = s.split("\\s+"):
            //for each word append to arraylist
            for(String s : parts)
            {
                 theWords.append(s);
            } //end for loop
 } //end while loop

// iterate array, from size-1 to 0
int theWordsSize = theWords.size()--;
for(int i= theWordsSize; i >= 0; i--)
{
     System.out.println(theWords.get(i));
 } //end for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

here the answer, It was easy:

public class Reverse2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



        if(args.length != 1){
            System.err.println("Sintaxis incorrecta, introduzca el nombre del fichero");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader br = null;


        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));

            ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
            String s;

            try {
                while((s=br.readLine()) != null){
                    lista.add(s);

                }

                for(int i= lista.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
                    System.out.println(lista.get(i));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





    }

}
```

thanks for all the possible solutions