# How to iterate a list in both directions?

Tags: java, iterator

I have a list of objects and want to iterate in forwards and backwards, until an element is found that is "valid".

```
MyClass {
    private boolean valid;
    public boolean isValid() { return valid; }
}

List<MyClass> classes; //assume sorted list
```

Now I want to start at position `idx`, and iterate both forwards and backwards to find the closest element that is valid. So far I already got the forward algorithm working. But I feel that the code could be optimized:

//supposed to start at position X

```
int idx = 10;

//find the closest element that is valid
for (ListIterator<MyClass> itr = classes.listIterator(idx); itr.hasNext();) {
    if (itr.hasNext()) {
        MyClass my = itr.next();
        while (!my.isValid()) {
            if (itr.hasNext()) {
                my = itr.next();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Sysout("the closest valid element is: " + my);
}
```

Could the iterator algorithm be written better?

Comment: Why don't you iterate with List.get(int index)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102499/iterating-through-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-java :: here for reverse order

Comment: use `iter.hasPrevious()` and `iter.previous()` like you do with `next()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two iterators at the same time. Start both of them at `idx`, and advance each of them in each iteration of the loop, until you hit the limit:

```
ListIterator<MyClass> fwd = classes.listIterator(idx);
ListIterator<MyClass> bck = classes.listIterator(idx);
MyClass found = null;
while (fwd.hasNext() || bck.hasPrevious()) {
    if (fwd.hasNext()) {
        MyClass my = fwd.next();
        if (my.isValid()) {
            found = my;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (bck.hasPrevious()) {
        MyClass my = bck.previous();
        if (my.isValid()) {
            found = my;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If `found` is `null` at the end of the loop, no valid items were found. Otherwise, `found` contains the nearest item to `idx`. If two valid items are located at the same distance from `idx`, the item located forward would be returned.

Comment: You've a typo in your while condition - the bck should check "hasPrevious".

Answer (score 1):

```
      package iteratorPract;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MyIterClass {
    private boolean valid;

    public boolean isValid() {
        return this.valid;
    }

    public void setValid(boolean valid) {
        this.valid = valid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyIterClass m1 = new MyIterClass();
        m1.setValid(true);
        MyIterClass m2 = new MyIterClass();
        List<MyIterClass> classes = new ArrayList<MyIterClass>();
        classes.add(m1);
        classes.add(m2);

        // from last
        ListIterator<MyIterClass> l1 = classes.listIterator(classes.size());

        while (l1.hasPrevious()) {
            if (l1.previous().isValid())
                System.out.println("it is valid");
            else
                System.out.println("not valid");
        }
        // from start
        ListIterator<MyIterClass> l2 = classes.listIterator();

        while (l1.hasNext()) {
            if (l1.next().isValid())
                System.out.println("it is valid");
            else
                System.out.println("not valid");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ListIterator#hasPrevious()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#hasPrevious%28%29) and [ListIterator#previous()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous%28%29) for backward iteration and
[ListIterator#hasNext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#hasNext%28%29) and [ListIterator#next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#next%28%29) for forward iteration with `ListIterator`.