# Iterating from the end of a list

Tags: java, list

I know that we can iterate over the list in the reverse order as follows:

```
List<Object> lst;
ListIterator<Object> i = lst.listIterator(lst.size());
```

But is it efficient if `lst` is a `LinkedList`? I mean when we obtain the `ListIterator` pointing to the end of the list, does the implementation iterate over the list from the begging to the `list.size()` position (takes `O(n)` time, where `n` is a size of the list)?

If it does, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Yes it does iterate over list list from the begging to the `list.size() `

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia So, in C++ we have reverse_iterator. How can it be done in Java efficiently?

Comment: list reverse order http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102499/iterating-through-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-java

Comment: @Satya They proposed the solution just as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @St.Antario You can implement you own doubly linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc states that LinkedList is a doubly-linked list, so I would expect `descendingIterator()`, which return an iterator pointing to the tail of the list, to be `O(1)`. Note that `descendingIterator` is from the `Deque` interface.

Now it is difficult to say whether the statement `lst.listIterator(lst.size())` is also `O(1)`, because it is not documented if `listIterator` method optimize the fact that the next element from `lst.size()` is the tail.

Comment: So, we just need to use the fact that it's a Deque, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator(int)) is a *"**Doubly-linked** list implementation of the List and Deque interfaces"*. So every element in the list has references to both the next AND the previous elements. So, the iterator should be as quick in the reverse order as it is in the natural order.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't iterate over the list to produce the iterator.

The best place to look for solutions to these is the [Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.ListItr).

```
  if (index < (size >> 1)) {
          next = header.next;
          for (nextIndex=0; nextIndex<index; nextIndex++)
              next = next.next;
      } else {
          next = header;
          for (nextIndex=size; nextIndex>index; nextIndex--)
              next = next.previous;
      }
```

As you can see, it will try to reach the index using the shortest path either from the first node or last node.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedList also implements Deque interface.

So if you implement it as

```
Deque list = new LinkedList();
```

Or if you additionally need the list methods

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
```

You can use

```
list.descendingIterator();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not work, the index `lst.size()` is out of bounds, maybe you meant `lst.size()-1`. But still it is not a reverse iterator, it is a forward iterator that instead of beginning at 0 will begin at the element you specify. In this case you will read only the last element then reach the end.

`LinkedList` implements interface [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#descendingIterator%28%29) which provides [Deque.descendingIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#descendingIterator%28%29). In this case both instancing the iterator and moving to the next (previous) element are `O(1)` operations. In the first case it's because the `Deque` implementation keeps a reference to both the beginning and the end of the queue, in the second because `LinkedList` is a doubly-linked list, in which every element keeps a reference to both its successor and his predecessor.

Comment: Now I see, you instanced it like that to iterate through previous(). In this case yes it works. But to be sure about complexity I'd go with Deque.reverseIterator(), even if at the end they should do the same operations.

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())`