# Elegant way to compare time sequence in forward/reverse order

Tags: java

Say my comparator function `foo` takes a time sequence as input, which could be a series of time from small to large, or from large to small.

`Foo` may look like this:

```
Foo(List<double> timestampList) {
  if (currentTime > previousMaxValueTimestamp) {
    ...
  } else if (curremtTime > previousMinValueTimestamp) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The above works for forward sequence, but not the reverse one. How can I elegantly write a logic that works for both types of sequence?
Below is what I want to do, but it duplicates most of the code, which is not desired.

```
Foo(List<double> timestampList, boolean isForward) {
  if (isForward) {
        if (currentTime > previousMaxValueTimestamp) {
            ...
        } else if (curremtTime > previousMinValueTimestamp) {
            ...
        }
  } else {
        if (currentTime < previousMaxValueTimestamp) {
            ...
        } else if (curremtTime < previousMinValueTimestamp) {
            ...
        }
  }
}
```

My current solution is like below. Is it good coding style?

```
Foo(List<double> timestampList, boolean isForward) {
    if ((isForward && currentTime > previousMaxValueTimestamp) || (!isForward && currentTime < previousMaxValueTimestamp)) {
        ...
    } else if ((isForward && curremtTime < previousMinValueTimestamp) || (!isForward && currentTime > previousMaxValueTimestamp)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: are all variables here Timestamps ? currentTime etc ? Because then you can simply use the methods from Timestamp, such as after or before (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

Comment: It's our self-defined timestamp, "double" typed. Not the general Timestamp.

Comment: Would sorting the list work?

Comment: This is critical section, we don't want extra overhead to sort or process the timestamp list.

Comment: based on your current solution I would suggest to extract the conditions in methods to give a meaningful name. This will make reading and understanding of the solution a lot easier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if something like this will still satisfy you, but in this way you can still reduce more or less your structure and you will not get this inflated code

```
if (isForward ? currentTime > previousMaxValueTimestamp :
    currentTime < previousMaxValueTimestamp)
{

} else if (!isForward ? currentTime < previousMaxValueTimestamp :
           currentTime < previousMinValueTimestamp)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list sorted as i suspect you do, you can simply use an iterator :

```
ListIterator li = a.listIterator(a.size());
while(isForward ? li.hasPrevious() : li.hasNext()) {
  nextItem = isForward ? li.previous() : li.next());
  //do stuff

}
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102499/iterating-through-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-java) and then edited to fit your needs

if your items are not pre-sorted and you can live with the pre-sorting overhead, you may use Collections.sort(yourList,yourSpecialComparator) providing your own special comparator.

Comment: In my case, the comparing logic is more complicated. Traversing reversely doesn't really help. Thanks though.

Comment: You can sort your list using Collections.sort(yourList,yourSpecialComparator) and the use the suggested approach.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicitly, have one "normal" comparator, and use .reverse() for descending lists. You can of course abstract it in a method if needed.