# How do I modify each element in an Iterable<T> in Java?

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I've searched as far as I can look and I'm struggling to find an answer to this question.. I have an Iterable object and I want to modify each item in it (I do NOT want to add to it) with a new value. I've tried

```
for (T e : list) 
{
    e = a.get(index);
    System.out.println(e);
    index--;
}
```

to modify it but that obviously didn't work, because it is a foreach loop. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong with this code? (The idea is that i'm trying to reverse my Iterable's item order.)

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
     Iterable<T> list;
     public LinkedList() {} //create an empty list
     public LinkedList(Iterable<T> iterable)
     {
         list = iterable;
     }
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     public Iterable<T> reverse()
     {
         Integer size = size();
         List<T> a = new ArrayList<T>();
         Integer index = size - 1;
         for (T e : list) 
         {
             a.add(e);
         }
         Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
         while (iterator.hasNext()) 
         {
             T element = (T)iterator.next();
             element = a.get(index);
             System.out.println(element);
             index--;
         }
         return list;
     }
}
```

Comment: As in, you want the iterable to have different elements when you're done? Not possible. Iterables don't work that way.

Comment: I just want to reverse the elements in the Iterable. Is that possible? @user2357112

Comment: You could return a "reverse iterator", but none of your code modifies anything... It isn't the fact that you are using a foreach loop, either

Comment: So, what would I do to actually modify the Iterable? @cricket_007

Comment: Check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102499/iterating-through-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-java

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste the part where I returned list! I modified it!

Comment: Collections can be modified. Iterables can't.

Comment: You can't modify the elements of an Iterable. Imagine if you could. An Iterable could be, for example, over the lines of text that you read from a network socket. How then would you modify those in order to reverse them? The answer is you can't. You can only reverse a List, or an array, or anything that has index-based get and set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand this loop construct:

```
for (T e : list)
```

This assigns to the variable `e`, a *copy* of a reference to some object in list.

You tried to assign a new value to `e`:

```
e = a.get(index);
```

But all this achieves is *overwriting your **copy** of the reference*. The list `list` continues to use the reference it has always used.

---

Your end goal is to return an iterable that travels in the reverse direction? You have a few options here.

- Keep the underlying list unchanged, but make a *custom* iterator to provide a reverse view on it. This iterator can supply an `Iterable<T>`, which you return.
- Shuffle around the contents of the underlying list, such that the *list itself* is in reverse order (you can use `Collections.reverse(list)` for this). Its natural iteration order will resemble a "reverse" iteration of the original list.
- Same as above, but instead of mutating the existing list: create a reversed *copy* of the list.

---

One thing that you're doing that will make this hard for yourself is this:

```
Iterable<T> list;
public LinkedList(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    list = iterable;
}
```

Does this *need* to accept something as specific as an `Iterable`? Could it instead accept a `List` (giving you the ability to lookup elements at any index)? If it **has** to be an `Iterable`, you may not have to *store* it as an Iterable. You could insert its contents into an `ArrayList`, and then your variable `list` could actually be a `List`.

Comment: The point is that `e` is a different variable. The fact that the reference is copied follows automatically.