# Java - Getting last occurrence of object in list with only partial data

Tags: java, list, lastindexof

Not sure if the title makes sense. but I am currently stuck trying to get the last occurrence of an object in a list. Let's say the object is compromised of ages (integers) and names (strings). I'm trying to get the last occurrence of the age "18" within the list, and retrieve the name. How would I go about this?

Current block of code I'm working with (Sorry, had to water it down a lot):

```
private List<Callable<Void>> createTasks(ArrayList<NamesAndAges> namesAndAges) {
        List<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>>();

        int endOfIndex = 0, beginningOfIndex = 0;

        for (NamesAndAges nameAndAge : namesAndAges) 
        {
            if (endOfIndex >= minSize && endOfIndex == namesAndAges.lastIndexOf(???))
            {
                tasks.add(new addIntoDB(namesAndAges.subList(beginningOfIndex, endOfIndex)));
                beginningofIndex = endOfIndex+1;
            }
            endOfIndex++;
        }
        return tasks;
    }
```

I'm basically stuck on where the ??? are in the code. I thought I could go about it using lastIndexOf().

Comment: This isn't a question about Java so much as a question of how to write a program, isn't it?  Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Reverse the List of objects and then traverse the List using for loop , `break` out of `for loop` on first occurrence of `age = 18`. If you provide some code i can give a better solution.

Comment: @scottb Oh, I thought it was a one liner. I was looking at the lastIndexOf() to see if there's a way to go about it using that. If it's longer than just one to two lines, then I guess I need to write a whole new function or class to go about it. My bad.

Comment: If what is a one liner?  You've not even showed us any code for the object you're working with.

Comment: @scottb Added the small chunk of code. I'll be executing the tasks at once to add into a database. I had it where a task would be added every 20 entries, but if a name and age matched exactly, I would get a primary key error due to the threads executing at once. Hence, if I ordered them all by ages and cut the tasks to be executed at age 22, 23, etc (then went through and removed duplicates per task), the error shouldn't occur.

Comment: I'm also trying to keep the minSize to 150 right now -- it can go over, but I want to try to find an efficient way since there can be over 100,000 entries.

Comment: Oh. So far, only viable solution is iterating forward. Not sure if it's the best solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102499/iterating-through-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-java), if you have a list, you can start your iterator at the end of the collection and iterate backwards:

```
// Substitute appropriate type.
ArrayList<MyItem> a = new ArrayList<MyItem>();

// add your elements...

// Generate an iterator. Start after the last element.
ListIterator li = a.listIterator(a.size());

// Iterate in reverse.
MyItem mi = null;
while(li.hasPrevious()) {
    mi = li.previous();
    if(mi.getAge().equals("18")) { // obviously, your test will likely differ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mm.. I guess it answers the question, but I thought there would be a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // add your elements...
    for(int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
    {
        a.add(i);
    }


    while(a.size() > 0) 
    {            
        System.out.println("last item: " + a.get(a.size() - 1));//print last item
        a.remove(a.size() - 1);//remove last item
    }
```